# Xpath to select only nodes where child has certain value

Tags: xpath, parent

Hope someone can help

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b>1.00</b>
        <c>
            <d/>
        </c>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b/>
    </a>
</root>
```

How can I formulate an XPATH expression in which I get b's value only if the parent node has a D node

i.e., in the previous example I would get only the value of the first b, as the second a node doesn't have a /c/d

Answer (score 1):

Try `//*[.//d]/b`

i.e. any `b` node, child of any node -- `*` -- that has a `d` descendant

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a *predicate* to filter

```
/root/a[c/d]/b
```

i.e. starting with the `root` element, find all its `a` children that have a `c/d`, and finally extract the `b` children of these filtered `a` elements.